# Como exportar algunos campos con sus registros a una nueva tabla postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Si tuviera una tabla con n campos y m registros y deseo crear una nueva tabla con algunos campos y todos los registros, entendiendo que hay campos que majenan imágenes entre otros formatos, como puedo importar esos registros y campos de la manera más óptima y luego poder eliminr la tabla antigua.¿Es posible crear un método que haga esos procedimientos de manera óptima si son una cantidad considerable de registros?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo lo haría directamente en *Postgresql* (fuera de *Rails*), un simple `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` es suficiente.

Por ejemplo, suponiendo que tengo una tabla llamada `origen` con los campos `campo1`, `campo2`, `campo3` y `campo4` pero solo quiero los campos `campo1` y `campo3` en una nueva tabla, llamada `destino`<sup>1</sup>, entonces utilizaría el siguiente *query*:

```
INSERT INTO destino (campo1, campo3)
SELECT campo1, campo3 FROM origen;
```

<sup><sup>1</sup> *Se asume que la tabla `destino` ya ha sido creada.*</sup>

Answer (score 1):

es breve en postgresql simplemente seria

```
create table tu_tabla_destino as select campo1,campo2 from tu_tabla_origen;
```

Comment: Hola User, bienvenido a [es.so]. Parece que esta pregunta ya esta respondida y aceptada. Te sugiero que publiques respuestas sin respuestas o sin ninguna aceptada. Un saludo ^^

Comment: @sstan acabo de ver el comentario por casualidad, faltaba el "6b" xD  por supuesto que si ya hay aceptada se puede publicar, pero poca atencion va a atraer del OP porque la mayoria de las veces dan el tema por zanjado. Mi comentario era por su situacion de recien llegado, es más facil empezar en preguntas activas.

Comment: Podrias comentar un poco mas la respuesta? que quiere decir en breve? y en que diferencia esto de la respuesta aceptada?

Comment: bueno que es facil, y la diferencia es que automaticamente se crea la tabla